# Slow Ruby Regex Becomes Fast with Odd Change

Tags: ruby, regex, pcre

I've been debugging a site to find the source of long page loading times, and I've narrowed it down to a regex that's used to extract URLs from text:

```
/(?:([\w+.-]+):\/\/|(?:www\.))[^\s<]+/g
```

This takes about 3 seconds to run on a large block of text. I found out that if I add the inverse of the first clause to the start of the regex (`(?:[^\w+.-]|^)`), it runs almost instantly:

```
/(?:[^\w+.-]|^)(?:([\w+.-]++):\/\/|(?:www\.))[^\s<]+/gx
```

It seems to me like the added clause shouldn't affect the regex at all, since nothing could cause that clause to fail (as those characters would be matched by the "[\w+.-]++" clause). Why does this make the regex run so much faster?

**Edit**

Some people have asked for an example of what I'm trying to do. To simplify things and to address the concerns people had in the comments, I'll be using the following two regexes:

```
# slow one
/(?:([\w+.-]+):\/\/|(?:www\.))[^\s<]+/g

# fast one
/[^\w+.-](?:([\w+.-]+):\/\/|(?:www\.))[^\s<]+/g
```

Fire up IRB/Pry and throw some text in a variable (this is a scrubbed version of what is actually searched against):

```
text = <<END_OF_TEXT
Unable to deliver message to email@example.com. Error message:  request: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=";http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot; xmlns:t=";http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/year/types&quot; xmlns:m=";http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/year/messages"><soap:Header&gt;<t:RequestServerVersion Version="ExchangeYear"/></soap:Header><soap:Body><m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy"><m:SavedItemFolderId><t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="stuff"/></m:SavedItemFolderId><m:Items><t:Message><t:MimeContent>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
END_OF_TEXT
```

Use the slow regex on it and note how slow it is:

```
text.gsub(/(?:([\w+.-]+):\/\/|(?:www\.))[^\s<]+/).to_a
```

Use the fast regex and note how fast it is:

```
text.gsub(/[^\w+.-](?:([\w+.-]+):\/\/|(?:www\.))[^\s<]+/).to_a
```

I figured out that this problem is specific to the type of data I used in the example (not a lot of spaces). If you run it against [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), which is much longer, both versions are equally fast.

Comment: What effect does removing the `x` modifier from the 2nd regex have on the speed? Might be that being able to ignore whitespace makes the 2nd option faster. (Pure speculation).

Comment: I just gave it a go but it took the same amount of time.

Comment: The second version may have a typo. In the middle of the regex you have two +'s side by site. Is this second regex properly collecting matches or testing or replacing or whatever it's supposed to do?

Comment: I suspect that it is because the additional clause you added contains an anchor to the start of the line:  the `|^` in `(?:[^\w+.-]|^)`. This will reduce the surface area that the regex has to check.

Comment: Also the \w+ inside the character classes for the protocol (before the `://` has a `+`, that's probably unnecessary and could cause false matches.

Comment: @cfqueryparam The ++ operator limits backtracing; it doesn't affect runtime by more than a fraction of a second either way. Also, the `+` after the `\w` matches literal "+" characters in the URI's scheme, which is technically allowed (though I agree it's probably unnecessary). @SeanKenny I also tried without the `|^`, though it still took ~3 seconds.

Comment: If you would like to see suggested changes to your regex, it would be helpful to include a short example text and the desired result.

Comment: @Yahooguntu what I mean to say is that the difference between the two regexes is more than just the first clause (regarding the two `++`). However, I wasn't aware that + was valid in the protocol portion of the url.

Comment: I don't believe Ruby supports the `/g` option. What is that? Is it related to `"pore"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland the `/g` was meant to indicate that this is being executed with `gsub`; check out the edit I just made and it should make more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first pattern is slow because it starts with an alternation and the first branch of the alternation is very permissive since it allows any number of words characters or dots or hyphens. Consequence, this alternation takes a lot of time/steps before failing.

The second pattern is faster because `(?:[^\w+.-]|^)` *(that is an alternation too)* works like a kind of anchor. Indeed, even it is an alternation, it is quickly tested because the first branch matches only one character and the second is a zero-width assertion. So it takes less time/steps to fail. *(in particular because it must be followed by a word character or a dot or an hypĥen, that is a binding condition)*

But you can write this pattern in a better way. Since your are looking for urls, you can be more precise for the begining: the url can begin with, lets say, "http", "ftp", "sftp", "gopher", "www" *(feel free to add other schemes if needed)*.
So you can describe the start with:

```
(?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|sftp:\/\/|gopher:\/\/|www\.)
```

To limit the cost of the alternation *(5 branches to test at each positions in the string)* you can use two tricks:

- you can use a word boundary to quickly skip positions that are not the start or the end of a word:

  `\b(?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|sftp:\/\/|gopher:\/\/|www\.)`
- you can add a lookahead with the first letter of each branches, to quickly avoid uneeded positions in the string without to test the five branches:

  `\b(?=[fghsw])(?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|sftp:\/\/|gopher:\/\/|www\.)`

So you can write a more efficient pattern like this:

```
/\b(?=[fghsw])(?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|sftp:\/\/|gopher:\/\/|www\.)[^\s<]+/
```

In short: a pattern is efficient when it fail fast at bad positions in the string.

An other possible design that uses more memory and needs to check if the capture group exists for each match, but that is faster:

```
/[^ghsfw]*+(?:\B[ghsfw][^ghsfw]*)*+|\b((?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|sftp:\/\/|gopher:\/\/|www\.)[^\s<"&]+)/
```

*(the idea is to divide the pattern in two main branches, the first one describes all that you want to avoid, and the second describes the urls. The effect is quick jumps to key positions in the string)*

Note: when patterns begin to be long, you can use the free-spacing mode (or comment mode...) for readability and maintainability:

```
/(?x)
\b (?=[fghsw])
(?:
    https?:\/\/  |
    ftp:\/\/     |
    sftp:\/\/    |
    gopher:\/\/  |
    www\.
)
[^\s<]+/
```

or you can use a formatted string and a join as suggested by  Cary Swoveland in comments.

Comment: Great answer, Casimir. Maintainability might be improved by replacing the line preceding your antipenultimate line with : `preface = %w{https? ftp sftp gopher}; str = (preface.map { |w| w << ':\/\/'} << 'www\.').join('|') #=> "https?:\\/\\/|ftp:\\/\\/|sftp:\\/\\/|gopher:\\/\\/|www\\."; r = /\b(?=[fghsw])(?:#{str})[^\s<]+/g`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I have to keep the URL schemes generic. Is there some way to utilize the anchor from the fast regex, but without matching the anchor character? (right now the fast regex includes random spaces, quotes, etc. at the start of the match)

Comment: @Yahooguntu: "I have to keep the URL schemes generic": Why? Do you need martian schemes? You should use an exhaustive list of schemes, even if there are a lot, it's not a problem with this kind of design.

Comment: I believe the issue is that there are schemes that I don't know about, but that this expression should still be able to handle. I read up a bit on negative lookbehind, and replaced `(?:[^\w+.-]|^)` with `(?<![\w+.:-])`, though I'm still a little unclear as to what's going on internally that would make this faster.

Comment: A sensible trie-izing optimizer should already do the equivalent of your last lookahead optimization. If it doesn't, it might after replacing `https?:\/\/` with `http:\/\/|https:\/\/`.

Comment: @hobbs: Not sure that a "pre-search" (a research of litteral strings positions with a fast algorithm before the regex engine walk) is possible when the pattern syntax is a bit complicated (understand the presence of several branches enclosed in a group) because this analyze step has to be very fast *(note that I don't know too if the ruby regex engine is able to do that)*. This is the reason why I suggested more hand-driven ways.

Comment: @hobbs: to illustrate this theory, see the example of PCRE that allows variable length lookbehinds only for an alternation of fixed strings. If you write `(?<=abc|defg|123)` it works, but if you write `(?<=(?:abc|defg|123))` the analyze is aborted and an error is returned.

Comment: @hobbs: if this kind of pre optimization exists in Ruby, perhaps it is possible to activate it if you write the pattern like that `http:\/\/[^\s><]+|https:\/\/[^\s><]+|...` without groups and with nothing in factor.